# Passed object is not updated by nested function call

Tags: powershell

I create a new object(1) with some properties.
I'm passing this object to a function(1), which then calls another function(2).
Function(2) itself creates an object(2) of the same type and returns it with `Write-Output`.
Then back in function(1) the object(1) gets assigned the return value.
As objects are passed by reference, I would expect, that object(1) will be updated outside of the function scope. But it is not.

Main script:

```
$RootFolder = "C:\xyz"

. "$RootFolder\FunctionFile - Copy.ps1"
. "$RootFolder\File - Copy.ps1"

$Object_Test = [PSCustomObject]::new()
$Object_Test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "a" -Value 0
$Object_Test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "b" -Value 0

Write-Host "Before function call: $Object_Test"
Initialize-ObjectMutation -Object $Object_Test
Write-Host "After function call: $Object_Test"
```

Function(1) ('File - Copy.ps1'):

```
function Initialize-ObjectMutation {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [PSCustomObject]$Object
    )

    Write-Host "Before function call (inside): $Object"
    $Object = New-Object
    Write-Host "After function call (inside): $Object"
}
```

Function(2) ('FunctionFile - Copy.ps1'):

```
function New-Object {
    $Object = [PSCustomObject]::new()
    $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "a" -Value 1
    $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "b" -Value 1

    Write-Output $Object
}
```

Output:

```
Before function call: @{a=0; b=0}
Before function call (inside): @{a=0; b=0}
After function call (inside): @{a=1; b=1}
After function call: @{a=0; b=0}
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong, or which concept I misunderstood here? Please also feel free to give advice on how I could solve this in a better way.
In real life, function(1) would do some more stuff and with another hand full of variables. It is actually a wrapper for function(2)-like functions.

Comment: Don't call `[PSCustomObject]::new()` inside of the function. Just update the passed in object instead.

Comment: Thanks AOT! This works. Would mark this as answer, as it looks smoother in my eyes then the answer from Hassan. Can you please explain, why it wasn't working the way I did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to get it to work using my own $RootFolder. Object is passed by reference and the values are copied from the returning function.

main.ps1

```
$RootFolder = "H:\Coding\stack"

. "$RootFolder\FunctionFile - Copy.ps1"
. "$RootFolder\File - Copy.ps1"

$Object_Test = [PSCustomObject]::new()
$Object_Test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "a" -Value 0
$Object_Test | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "b" -Value 0

Write-Host "Before function call: $Object_Test"
Initialize-ObjectMutation -Object ([ref]$Object_Test)
Write-Host "After function call: $Object_Test"
```

File - Copy.ps1

```
function Initialize-ObjectMutation {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ref]$Object
    )

    Write-Host "Before function call (inside): $($Object.value)"
    
    $return = New-Object

    $Object.value.a = $return.a;
    $Object.value.b = $return.b;

    Write-Host "After function call (inside): $($Object.value)"
}
```

FunctionFile - Copy.ps1

```
function New-Object {
    $Object = [PSCustomObject]::new()
    $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "a" -Value 1
    $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "b" -Value 1

    return $Object
}
```

Results

```
PS H:\Coding\stack> ./main.ps1
Before function call: @{a=0; b=0}
Before function call (inside): @{a=0; b=0}
After function call (inside): @{a=1; b=1}
After function call: @{a=1; b=1}
```

Comment: Hi Hassan, thanks a lot, this is working! But I really hoped I could avoid this [ref] thing... Can someone explain, why the object wasn't passed by reference in the first line? It works if there is no new object created in function 'New-Object'. Is it because the $Object becomes a reference to the 'new object' from New-Object?

Comment: Hey, it also works if I'm doing this in 'File - Copy.ps1': `$Object_New = New-Object; $Object.a = $Object_New.a; $Object.b = $Object_New.b`.